# Passing data through a jQuery .post() function

Tags: jquery, post

I usually pass data through .post() like this:

```
 $.post(
    "/ajax.php",
    $("#form").serialize(),
    function(responseJSON) {
        console.log(responseJSON);
    },
    "html"
);
```

Within my form `"#form"` I usually have a hidden input with the name "id" which holds a value to the id of the item I want to run queries on.

What I want to do is take out that hidden input and add in a `data-id="$id"` attribute in my submit button and have the jQuery function extract the data from there and send that along with the other `#form` fields.

In simple terms what I'm asking is how do I pass along `$('#form').serialize()` along with `$('#button').data('id')` over to my back end all in one `$.post()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var data = $("#form").serialize() + '&data-id=' + $('#button').data('id');
$.post(
    "/ajax.php",
    data,
    function(responseJSON) {
        console.log(responseJSON);
    },
    "html"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

.serialize() just creates a string with the data.  You just need to append `&<variable>=<value>` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

you may try a library that does that for you automatically, you don't need to worry about the inner workings, using http://phery-php-ajax.net/

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
   'function' => function($data){ 
       // $data['id'] = the hidden in your form
       return PheryResponse::factory()->json($your_array_that_will_be_turned_to_json);
   }
))->process();
```

```html
<form data-remote="function" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id">
</form>
```

In your Javascript, you may deal with the JSON

```js
$(function(){
  $('form').bind('phery:json', function(event, json_data){
    // deal with your json_data
  }
});
```